# iOS 10 Control Center does not feature Music buttons

Tags: iphone, ios

What feels missing here are the music controls `<< || >>`. They *are* on the lock screen before you unlock the phone. However, it happens a lot of times that I accidentally unlock the phone, even though I want to perform operations on the lock screen.

Having the music controls here is also an easy way to navigate through the playlist without having to switch to the Music app.

Is there any way to bring back these buttons, or is there a new way in **iOS 10**?

[image: Control Center]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swipe the Control Center to the side. The media controls are on a separate page indicated by the page icons at the bottom of the screen, accessible by swiping horizontally.

You are informed of this the first time you open Control Center after upgrading to iOS 10.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Although, I wonder why AirPlay and Night Shift controls seem more important to apple than the Music controls. In my opinion these two should be switched. But hey, the controls are there, even though a little obscure. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @bytecode77 Control Center remembers the card you were on (I believe until the phone is hard reset) so if you prefer Music controls, those should stay present.